# When using data binding In Xml MutableLiveData not suggested by Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

When we use MutableLiveData in ViewModel when we use it in XML, Android Studio does not offer it to us?

```
public class LoginViewModel extend ViewModel {

    public MutableLiveData<UserEntity> userEntity;

    public UserEntity userEntity1;

}
```

[image: public UserEntity userEntity1;]

[image]

userEntity1 is Work  but userEntity is not work.

How to resolve this problem?

Update:

The Android Studio 3.4.2 is fixed this bug.

Comment: what version of AS are you using?

Comment: Version android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1

Comment: i am asking about **A**ndroid **S**tudio

Comment: Android Studio 3.1.2
Build #AI-173.4720617, built on April 14, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem? If so, then please accept it (green tick).

Comment: When change to another type does not automatic update view.

Comment: The Android Studio 3.4.2 is fixed this bug.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have public getters in your view model to access the fields from the xml.

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<UserEntity> userEntity;

    //Mandatory zero parameter constructor, if non zero parameter constructor is necessary, a factory needs to be created for the ViewModel
    public LoginViewModel() {}

    //Option 1: Public getter for the userEntity object
    public MutableLiveData<UserEntity> getUserEntity() {
        return userEntity;
    }

    //Option 2: Alternatively a separate getter can be used for different fields of the model class
    public String getUserName() {
        return userEntity.getValue().getName();
    }
}
```

Then you can access fields in the xml like this:

Option 1:

```
android:text="@{userEntityViewModel.user.name}"
```

Option 2:

```
android:text="@{userEntityViewModel.userName}"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In this approach, I have a doubt that it doesn't update any value in the model itself because it doesn't have any setter method.